# Reorder displayed posts with JQuery (title A-Z / last posted)

Tags: jquery, order

just wondering if anyone came across this: I have a front page featuring artists in a square grid, now the client asks for a switch button to reorder the artist from A-Z (based on artist name) to the conventional newest post first - but this shall happen without reloading the page.

I found a solution with giving a parameter and then reload the page updating the query, but client wants this happing "on the fly" like here: http://selectiveartists.com/

Probably there is a solution to change order of posts with help of some JQuery (Plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

With WordPress you can utilise a function called [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) which allows you to pass in a script, and a variable you would like that script to have access too.

Perhaps by assigning the new query to a variable, and then accessing it within jQuery would help you solve  your problem.

The example provided by WordPress explains it pretty clearly:

```
<?php
  // Register the script
  wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

  // Localize the script with new data
  $translation_array = array(
       'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
       'a_value' => '10');

  wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

  // Enqueued script with localized data.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
?>
```

And then access like so:

```
<script>
  // alerts 'Some string to translate'
  alert( object_name.some_string);
</script>
```

So as you can see Javascript is now getting access to the variable translation_array variable by getting hold of the object_name which is tied to the variable $translation_array and is then pulling the value of some_string from the array.

So we could write something along the lines of:

```
<?php 
    $args = array('order' => 'ASC');
    $get_artists = get_posts($args);

    wp_register_script('artists', 'path/to/artists.js');
    wp_localize_script('artists', 'artist_sort', $get_artists);

    wp_enqueue_script('artists');
?>
```

And then access the variable within our artists.js script.

*[ No Idea if this works, as I haven't tested it, just purely an example in how you might be able to go about it ]*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer EBennett, i just found that handy jQuery snippet which allows me to sort list item ascending and descending via the posts title. If anyone is interested, here is the code i adapted to fit my needs: 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/PmE2t/88/light/